# Is there a readable resource that can tell me what is valid html

Tags: html, verify

I always have questions like: "Can I have such a path -> ul > div > li ?" I never know how to google these questions as it would work but wouldn't verify. Is there a resource that explains, in simple english (not w3), what I can and can't do?

I always see people saying you can't have a bar inside a foo and so on. Where can I find this out?

Comment: Consider that it may be too complicated for "simple English" to explain adequately.

Comment: Are you looking for a complier...?

Comment: There are over 8 million results when you ask google for `html validator`. Check the links starting from result #2.

Comment: It might be an idea to actually try to learn HTML, it really is quite easy. Trial and error with a validator might not be such a good way forward :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the W3C  [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or if you're using Firefox you can install the [HTML validator addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/), these tools will tell you about problems like the one you mentioned in your question and they work according to the W3C resources.

Answer (score 0):

the w3 resources are the official available. they're not really hard to read!

to know /properly/ what can be contained in what, you should read the DTD files. they're not simple english...